# Doctrine limit is breaking my query?

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have the following code:

```
$params = array();
$query_questions_visibles = questionTable::getInstance()->createQuery("q")
    ->select("q.*, ua.*, a.*, u.*, c.*")
    ->leftJoin("q.Answers a")
    ->leftJoin("a.UserAnswers ua")
    ->Where("q.blocked = false")
    ->andWhere("ua.user_id = :user_id")
->orderBy("q.id DESC")
->groupBy("q.id");

    //Subquery --> Calculates when a question is active or not      
    $format = sfConfig::get("app_datetime_format");
    $active_time = date($format, strtotime(sfConfig::get("app_question_active_time")));
    $sub_query_is_active = $query_questions_visibles->createSubQuery()
            ->select("MAX(ua0.created_at)")
            ->from("question q0")
            ->leftJoin("q0.Answers a0")
            ->leftJoin("a0.UserAnswers ua0")
            ->where("q0.id = q.id");                
    $query_questions_visibles->addSelect("COALESCE((".$sub_query_is_active.") > :active_time, false) as Active");

//Set param values
$params["user_id"] = $guardUser->id;
$params["active_time"] = $active_time;

$result = $query_questions_visibles->execute($params);
```

The previous code works as expected.

Generated SQL is complete and works:

> SELECT q.id AS q__id, q.user_id AS q__user_id, q.category_id AS q__category_id, q.gender_restriction AS q__gender_restriction, q.question AS q_*question, q.photo AS q*_photo, q.latitude AS q_*latitude, q.longitude AS q*_longitude, q.multiple AS q_*multiple, q.blocked AS q*_blocked, q.created_at AS q__created_at, q.updated_at AS q__updated_at, a.id AS a__id, a.question_id AS a__question_id, a.text AS a_*text, u.id AS u*_id, u.user_id AS u__user_id, u.answer_id AS u__answer_id, u.created_at AS u__created_at, u.updated_at AS u__updated_at, COALESCE((SELECT MAX(u2.created_at) AS u2__0 FROM question q2 LEFT JOIN answer a2 ON q2.id = a2.question_id LEFT JOIN user_answer u2 ON a2.id = u2.answer_id WHERE (q2.id = q.id)) > :active_time, 0) AS u2__0 FROM question q LEFT JOIN answer a ON q.id = a.question_id LEFT JOIN user_answer u ON a.id = u.answer_id WHERE (q.blocked = 0 AND u.user_id = :user_id) GROUP BY q.id ORDER BY q.id DESC

But, if I want to limit results, I modify the end lines as:

```
$query_questions_visibles->limit(10);
$result = $query_questions_visibles->execute($params);
```

Doctrine throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
>
> at Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT DISTINCT q2.id FROM question q2 LEFT JOIN answer a2 ON q2.id = a2.question_id LEFT JOIN user_answer u2 ON a2.id = u2.answer_id WHERE q2.blocked = 0 AND u2.user_id = :user_id GROUP BY q2.id ORDER BY q2.id DESC LIMIT 10', array('user_id' => '1', 'active_time' => '2013-03-17 17:12:12')) in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Query.php line 1290 ...

My purpose is only limit the query to 10 results, ¿where is my Subquery with COALESCE and MAX functions? ¿Why there's a SELECT DISTINCT who I never specified? ¿Why is selecting only q.id?

I spend all day trying to figure it out, i have no answer...
Any Ideas why setting a limit causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `limit()` to the Doctrine query then the Doctrine internals create in fact two queries. The first one select a limited set of distinct ids based on the conditions of your query. The second query selects the actual objects limiting the select to the ids found with the first query.

The problem with your query is that you use params inside of the `select` part, which is not used in the first query.

The only solutuion that comes to my mind is to add the value of the `active_time` parameter directly to the select part, without using the named param. It might not be the nicest solution but I can't think of a different one right now. The `addSelect()` does not accept additional parameters like `where()` does which could fix the issue (with `where()` you can use: `->where('field > ?', $value)`).

Comment: Hi @Michal, it's weird, i have many similar `Doctrine_Querys` using named params and subquerys and ir works. Only this one is having problems.
My real query is about 3 or 4 times bigger than this, i need to use named params because i'm using many subquerys.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using the named params in the `select` part **and** a `limit` statement in those other cases? Complexity has (nearly) nothing to do with the fact you'll use params or not (place the values directly in the query). Using named params is doing it more "the Doctrine way", but if there's no other way you might have to drop them.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same subquery to calculate when the question is active or not in the other queries, and the other big query is using limit too, and works ok... it's very weird.

Reviewing my current query, there is only one `addSelect()` with named parameters (the same as the example).

I have others like `addSelect("(".otherSubquery->getDql().") as Value")`; in `otherSubquery` there are named parameters as well.

Really its a good idea replacing: `COALESCE((".$sub_query_is_active.") > :active_time` for `COALESCE((".$sub_query_is_active.") > $active_time`? this could be a security problem?

Comment: I don't understand why I can use almost the same query in one place using named params and works well... anyway, i follow @Michal suggestion, I changed some named params (:param) and replaced them with $param directly in the string and it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: It must the difference of using the query or the generated Dql (using `$sub_query_is_active` against `$otherSubquery->getDql()`) though you would have to dig into the internals to see what is going on there.

Comment: As for security - if `$active_time` can be read from the user input it's propably a good idea to escape it manually. If the value is only set within the script that shouldn't be a security issue.